# What diagnostic tools are available for Node.js applications?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, diagnostics

There are many tools out there, which diagnostics tools are good for diagnostic memory leak issues for node.js applications?

Comment: One tool that I am using is the IBM Interactive Diagnostic Data Explorer tools (IDDE).    Basically if I suspect there is some leak in the application over time. I will take different snapshots of core dump of the node.js process over time and then use the IDDE  command line tools to analyze the core dump.  They also have eclipse base GUI version.

Comment: What commands are useful?

Comment: I find this command jsmeminfo very useful.  jsmeminfo will show 5 larges heap objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IDDE is a powerful tool not only for memory leak detection, but for a wide variety of problem determination of Node.js misbehaviors, including crashes and hangs.

Here is the link for overview, installation, and what is new information: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/idde

1. I would start with nodeoverview command. Note that every command starts with a bang (!) and every command is entered with a control (ctrl+enter) for reasons.

!nodeoverview {

### Heap and Garbage Collection

Memory allocator, used: 981 MB, available: 482 MB
GC Count: 144

This shows up the occupancy of the heap.

2. Then, use jsmeminfo to figure out the predominent resident objects in the heap.

   !jsmeminfo {

   Memory allocator, used: 981 MB, available: 482 MB
   Total Heap Objects: 21559924

   Largest 5 heap objects  Type               Size (bytes)  More information

   ---

   0x00000000de06d319      FIXED_ARRAY_TYPE         131112  !array 0x00000000de06d319 
   0x00000000de0ac6d9      FIXED_ARRAY_TYPE          98360  !array 0x00000000de0ac6d9 
   0x00000000e90e2f09      ASCII_STRING_TYPE         48152  !string 0x00000000e90e2f09
   0x00000000e9035099      ASCII_STRING_TYPE         48088  !string 0x00000000e9035099
   0x00000000e9004101      ASCII_STRING_TYPE         40936  !string 0x00000000e9004101

   Most Frequent 5 object types    Frequency

   ---

   JS_OBJECT_TYPE                   15371393
   FIXED_ARRAY_TYPE                  6175379
   ASCII_INTERNALIZED_STRING_TYPE       3476
   BYTE_ARRAY_TYPE                      1572
   JS_FUNCTION_TYPE                     1434

   }
3. Review the application based on this information and see they holding up the memory as shown is justified or not.
4. If you want to 'dissect' the objects further to see the content, use object expansion commands such as !jsobject or !array:

   !array 0x00000000de06d319 {

   Array type : FIXED_ARRAY_TYPE
   Len : 16387
   Showing first 100 elements only
   0 : 0xd9400000000 (SMI)
   1 : 0x3fe00000000 (SMI)
   2 : 0x400000000000 (SMI)
   3 : 0x9a1103d1 (ASCII_INTERNALIZED_STRING_TYPE : !print 0x000000009A1103D1 )
   4 : 0x9a1042a9 (ASCII_INTERNALIZED_STRING_TYPE : !print 0x000000009A1042A9 )
   ...
   }
5. If you want to 'segregate' the entire heap into sections based on object's internal types, user jsgroupobjects. This is more useful when you have multiple dumps taken at different time intervals, and want to compare which objects grew over time.

   !jsgroupobjects {

   Representative Object Address  Object Type           Num Objects  Constructor    Num Properties  Properties

   ---

   !jsobject 0x00000000c8244fd1   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        6133503      Object         0
   !jsobject 0x00000000c8004161   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        6133499      Database       0
   !jsobject 0x00000000c8004101   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        3066750      MyRecord       0
   !jsobject 0x00000000c869b111   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        37302        Object         0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de05b959   JS_FUNCTION_TYPE      542              0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de04bcc1   JS_FUNCTION_TYPE      267              0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de04aa09   JS_FUNCTION_TYPE      251              0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de04a911   JS_FUNCTION_TYPE      227              0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de0a48c9   JS_ARRAY_TYPE         190          Array          0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de04a7e9   JS_FUNCTION_TYPE      102              0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de04e379   JS_ARRAY_TYPE         34           Array          0
   !jsobject 0x00000000de050db1   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        30           Object         0
   !jsobject 0x00000000c2938151   JS_REGEXP_TYPE        18           RegExp         0
   !jsobject 0x00000000c2955a11   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        15           NativeModule   0
   !jsobject 0x00000000c2944519   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        11           Object         0
   !jsobject 0x00003abc617bee71   JS_OBJECT_TYPE        102          CallSite       3               receiver, fun, pos
6. If you want to examine a single object, do jsobject on the object address.

   !jsobject 0x00003abc617bee71 {

   Object has fast properties
   Number of descriptors : 3

   Name      Value               More Information

   ---

   receiver  0x0000251abe506c91  
   fun       0x00003abc617bb241  
   pos       0x00001dfd00000000  SMI = 0x1dfd

   }

Comment: Thank you , this is informative, so does this tool work for node 0.12.x version as well as 0.10.x version>

Comment: yes, both node.js versions are supported, but currently you need to use the IBM SDK for Node.js  for this to work and Mac/OS is not supported.

Comment: so mac is not supported, what platforms does it support ?

Comment: Basically everything else,   x86 platforms -x Linux, windows, Linux on system Z, Linux on power.

Answer (score 0):

module https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics  but it is more for monitoring and profiling.
You can check it out, it is useful.